# archiva/jetty with nginx ssl proxy: getting http responses

Tags: nginx, ssl, jetty

I've been banging my head against this for awhile now. I have an archiva repository server I'm trying to proxy through nginx with ssl offloading. archiva has a jetty server built in that is listening on port 8008 of the localhost. I'm able to get to the archiva server through the proxy, but it wants to return http responses and not https responses. I thought that setting the following headers was supposed to tell the server to respond with https:

```
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect     off;
```

I also tried "proxy_redirect  default;".
It seems that the jetty/archiva server is not recognizing these or there needs to be something more. I've been scouring forums and as far as I can tell, everything is set as it should be. I'm not sure where else to check at this point. Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: At the moment, I have a workaround that I'm not proud of. In nginx.conf I added a rewrite to port 80: `server {...          location / {...            rewrite     ^   https://$host$request_uri? permanent;`

Comment: can you please post your server-config?

Comment: I'm still getting tripped up by Redback's CSRF check, since protocols don't match.

Answer (score 1):

```
    upstream archiva.example.com {
            server 127.0.0.1:8084;
}

# Serve Local Webserver Out of Proxy
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name archiva.example.com;
    rewrite     ^(.*)   https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {

    listen                  443;
    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate .....
server_name  you.example.com;

   location / {
       proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8084;
       proxy_set_header         host archiva.example.com;
   }
}
```